# Julia returns unexpected values

Tags: python, julia

I am a frequent user of Python for ML and am interested in converting to Julia for its promising improvements in speed. To get a feel for this I have just written a simple loop in both Python and Julia in order to compare the runtime for each one, but I seem to be getting unexpected results in the Julia implementation.

Here are both versions:

In Julia:

```
B = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, 10000,10000)

function f(x)
    return x^2
end

function g(x)
    return x^3
end

function h(x)
    return x^4
end

function compose(f,g,h,x)
    return f(g(h(x)))
end

for i in 1:10000
    for j in 1:10000
        B[i,j] = compose(f,g,h,i+j)
    end
end

println(sum(B))
```

In Python:

```
import numpy as np

B = np.zeros((10000, 10000), dtype=np.float64)

def f(x):
    return x**2

def g(x):
    return x**3

def h(x):
    return x**4

def compute(x):
    return f(g(h(x)))

for i in range(10000):
    for j in range(10000):
        B[i, j] = compute(i+j+2)

print(np.sum(B))
```

EDIT: The Julia version returns ~8.3e22 while Python returns ~1.0e109 (which is what I expect).

While the Julia version runs extremely fast compared to the Python version, its results aren't what I expect them to be. As mentioned above, I am using Julia for the first time here, but I can't see where my mistake might be. Is this a result of my array/datatype handling? Are my functions not doing what I think they are?

Comment: `range(10000)` produces the range 0..9999 whereas `1:10000` expands to 1..10000

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I assume that is the reason of `+ 2` in python.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych indeed

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you compared the two codes, but on my machine Julia is simply 1000X faster.

```
f(x) = x^2
g(x) = x^3
h(x) = (x^2)^2
compute(x) = f(g(h(x)))

function compute_sum(B)
    for j in 1:10000
        for i in 1:10000
            B[i,j] = compute(i+j+0.0)
        end 
    end 
    sum(B)
end

B = zeros(10000, 10000)
@time compute_sum(B)
1.0337869071875959e109
  0.126618 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
```

And Python:

```
from time import time

t0 = time()
for i in range(10000):
    for j in range(10000):
        B[i, j] = compute(i+j+2)

s = np.sum(B)
print('Time:', time()-t0, 'sec')
print(s)
Time: 126.33235883712769 sec
1.0337869071875948e+109
```

Comment: Thanks :) this seems to follow on from @Przemyslaw Szufel 's answer, converting to using floats with ```+0.0``` instead of ```Float64```.

Comment: Is there a particular reason as to why you wrote ```h(x) = (x^2)^2``` instead of ```h(x) = (x^4)```?

Comment: Yes, powers of 2 and 3 in Julia are so fast because they are inlined as `x^2 = x*x` and `x^3 = x*x*x`, but `x^4` and more are not calculated like that. The function `power_by_squaring` is used in case of 4 and beyond which can be 10X slower than inlining but more accurate. There is also the [FastPow.jl](https://github.com/JuliaMath/FastPow.jl) package which makes that much faster using the `@fastpow` macro.

Comment: This isn't quite correct. In Julia prior to 1.8, `x^4` (for `x::Float64`) is computed by converting `4` to `4.0` and using libm to compute a floating point power. As of Julia 1.8, `x^4` will use a compensated power by squaring that is roughly 3x slower than `(x^2)^2`.

Comment: Thanks for the precise information.

Answer (score 2):

I consolidated your code into a block so that it is easier to time. I then did a few revisions of your code below to improve performance.

1. The main issue with the correct number is due to integer overflow since `i` and `j` start as type `Int64`. Since we are storing as a `Float64` in the end, cast the input to `Float64`.
2. By putting the main contents of your code into a function, we can take advantage of compilation.

```
function f(x)
    return x^2
end

function g(x)
    return x^3
end

function h(x)
    return x^4
end

function compose(f,g,h,x)
    return f(g(h(x)))
end

println("Global block")

@time begin
    # B is an untyped global
    B = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, 10000,10000)
    for i in 1:10000
        for j in 1:10000
            # The i and j are of type Int64
            # You are experiencing integer overflow
            B[i,j] = compose(f,g,h,i+j)
        end
    end

    println(sum(B))
end


println("Global block with global typed")

@time begin
    # In recent versions of Julia, we can bind the type of globals
    BB :: Matrix{Float64} = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, 10000,10000)
    for i in 1:10000
        for j in 1:10000
            # Cast to Float64 to fix the integer overflow
            BB[i,j] = compose(f,g,h,Float64(i+j))
        end
    end

    # This should yield the correct answer
    println(sum(BB))
end

function main()
    # It is best to contain in functions that can be compiled
    # We also do not have to worry about binding globals to types
    # The following are all _local_ variables
    B = Array{Float64, 2}(undef, 10000,10000)
    T = eltype(B)
    for i in 1:10000
        @simd for j in 1:10000
            @inbounds B[i,j] = compose(f,g,h,T(i+j))
        end
    end

    println(sum(B))
end

# Execute twice to check for compilation time
println("Main 1:")
@time main() # first executing may include compilation time
println("Main 2:")
@time main() # should already be compiled now

function better()
    # As Ronny suggests, you can perform this calculation without allocating the array, saving time
    sum = 0.0
    for i in 1:10000
        for j in 1:10000
            sum += compose(f,g,h,Float64(i+j))
        end
    end
    println(sum)
end

println("Better 1:")
@time better()
println("Better 2:")
@time better()
```

When I execute this, I get the following results on my slow computer:

```
$ time julia stackoverflow.jl 
Global block
8.295592414458568e22
 11.718994 seconds (277.65 M allocations: 4.897 GiB, 5.85% gc time, 1.77% compilation time)

Global block with global typed
1.0337869071875959e109
 12.062228 seconds (289.78 M allocations: 5.063 GiB, 4.90% gc time, 0.07% compilation time)

Main 1:
1.0337869071875959e109
  2.575255 seconds (11 allocations: 762.940 MiB, 1.20% gc time)

Main 2:
1.0337869071875959e109
  2.626251 seconds (10 allocations: 762.940 MiB)

Better 1:
1.0337869071880225e109
  1.846267 seconds (8 allocations: 576 bytes)

Better 2:
1.0337869071880225e109
  1.844846 seconds (8 allocations: 576 bytes)

real    0m33.436s
user    0m26.216s
sys 0m7.623s
```

```
julia> versioninfo()
Julia Version 1.8.1
Commit afb6c60d69a (2022-09-06 15:09 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: Linux (x86_64-linux-gnu)
  CPU: 8 × AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-13.0.1 (ORCJIT, bdver1)
  Threads: 1 on 8 virtual cores
```

Note that you can also do this in a single line.

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @benchmark mapreduce(∘(f,g,h,Float64,t->t[1]+t[2]), +,  Iterators.product(1:10000, 1:10000))
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 3 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  1.783 s …  1.791 s  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     1.784 s             ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   1.786 s ± 4.441 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  █    █                                                 █  
  █▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁█ ▁
  1.78 s        Histogram: frequency by time        1.79 s <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer in Julia is 64-bit (unlike Python which has no size limit)
You have integer number overflow.

One option is to iterate over `Float64`s

```
jula> using BenchmarkTools 

julia> @btime B = [compose($f,$g,$h,i+j) for i in 1.0:10000.0, j in 1.0:10000.0]
  859.809 ms (2 allocations: 762.94 MiB)
10000×10000 Matrix{Float64}:
...
```

Note that `$` signs are required to correctly measure speed with `BenchmarkTools` macros, normally in the code you will not put them.

Answer (score 1):

I think one can even get that a little faster by omitting the `B` and using the iterator feature of the sum

```
f(x) = x^2
g(x) = x^3
h(x) = (x^2)^2
compute(x) = f(g(h(x)))

large_sum(n) = sum(compute(i+j+0.0) for i=1:n, j=1:n)
    
@time large_sum(10000)
```

yields

```
  0.115042 seconds
1.0337869071880225e109
```

and

```
julia> @allocated large_sum(10000)
0
```

*edit:* If you want to go for integers (for me the solution of @AboAmmar seems to indicate Python might do Float64 as well?) you can do

```
large_sum2(n) = sum(compute(big(i+j)) for i=1:n, j=1:n)
@time s = large_sum2(10000)
```

which yields

```
46.161187 seconds (1.60 G allocations: 37.124 GiB, 23.40% gc time)
10337869071875958659210675038435022389685259621942996488934459692733527441076067397940855599887078973410000000
```

and

```
julia> Float64(s)
1.0337869071875959e109
```

which still seems to be faster than the Python solution (of @ AboAmmar)

Comment: Ah very good, this takes about half the time on my machine :)